# Getting zero when extracting data from a PHP array in Laravel app

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Am working on some set of PHP array. Am trying to loop through each of them and check
the array whose name is equal to Josw Acade. Am using a for loop but I get zero
after extracting the data. I want to store the data in an array.

**Array**

```
array:6 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Josw Acade"
    "value" => "Unlimited"
    "plan_type" => "Superior"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Verbal"
    "value" => "true"
    "plan_type" => "Superior"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "id" => 12
    "name" => "Josw Acade"
    "value" => "$1,500,00"
    "plan_type" => "Classic"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [
    "id" => 13
    "name" => "Leon"
    "value" => "true"
    "plan_type" => "Classic"
  ]
  4 => array:4 [
    "id" => 14
    "name" => "One Time"
    "value" => "true"
    "plan_type" => "Classic"
  ]
  5 => array:4 [
    "id" => 15
    "name" => "Deat"
    "value" => "$25,000"
    "plan_type" => "Classic"
  ]
  6 => array:4 [
    "id" => 23
    "name" => "Josw Acade"
    "value" => "$100,000"
    "plan_type" => "Essential"
  ]
]
```

**Logic**

```
$Inst = [];
for($med = 0; $med < count($array); $med++){
    if($med['name'] == "Josw Acade"){
        $Inst = $med['value'];
    }
}

dd($Inst);
```

Comment: what is `$pkg` ... you have a loop initializing a variable `$med` to `0` then you are using that variable as an array `$med['name']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` with `callback`

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($v){ return $v['name'] == 'Josw Acade'})
print_r($filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variables is not corretly set in the for loop, you are setting `$med = 0` and acessing `$med` as an `array`.

Use filter, that runs a condition on each element and returns the items that satisfy that condition.

```
array_filter($array, function ($item) {
    return $item['name'] === 'Josw Acade';
});
```

In general you don't have to make old school arrays anymore, foreach does the same.

```
$results = [];

foreach($array as $item) 
{
    if ($item['name'] === 'Josw Acade') {
        $results[] = $item['value'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through array; so on each iteration to get values; you need to pass index value and you are missing that. You are using `$med` as index.

Here is code.

```
$Inst = [];
for($med = 0; $med < count($array); $med++){
    if($array[$med]['name'] == "Josw Acade"){
        $Inst[] = $array[$med]['value'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is many way to do this but according to me the best way to use [array_filer()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
array_filter($array, function ($item) {
    return $item['name'] === 'Josw Acade';
});
```